# How to merge columns interspersing the data?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm new to python and pandas and working to create a Pandas MultiIndex with two independent variables: flow and head which create a dataframe and I have 27 different design points. It's currently organized in a single dataframe with columns for each variable and rows for each design point.

Here's how I created the MultiIndex:

```
flow = df.loc[0, ["Mass_Flow_Rate", "Mass_Flow_Rate.1", 
"Mass_Flow_Rate.2"]]
dp = df.loc[:,"Design Point"]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dp, flow], names= 
['DP','Flows'])
```

I then created three columns of data:

```
 df0 = df.loc[:,"Head2D"]
 df1 = df.loc[:,"Head2D.1"]
 df2 = df.loc[:,"Head2D.1"]
```

And want to merge these into a single column of data such that I can use this command:

```
pc = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```

Using the three columns with the same indexes for the rows (0-27), I want to merge the columns into a single column such that the data is interspersed. If I call the columns col1, col2 and col3 and I denote the index in parentheses such that col1(0) indicates column1 index 0, I want the data to look like:

```
col1(0)
col2(0)
col3(0)
col1(1)
col2(1)
col3(1)
col1(2)...
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you it would be great if you could show us your initial DataFrame and your desired outcome

Comment: welcome to SO, your post is somewhat confusing, it looks like df1 is the same as df2, is that on purpose? also, is data the result of merging your three columns?

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit confusing. But what I understood is that you are trying to do this:

```py
flow = df.loc[0, ["Mass_Flow_Rate", "Mass_Flow_Rate.1", 
"Mass_Flow_Rate.2"]]
dp = df.loc[:,"Design Point"]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dp, flow], names= 
['DP','Flows'])
 df0 = df.loc[:,"Head2D"]
 df1 = df.loc[:,"Head2D.1"]
 df2 = df.loc[:,"Head2D.1"]

data = pd.concat[df0, df1, df2]
pc = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
```